# Hibernate Search - search in ManyToOne relation

Tags: hibernate-search

I have two indexed entities.
Player:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Player {

    @Field
    private String firstName;

    @ContainedIn
    @ManyToOne
    private Club playersClub;

}
```

and Club:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Club {

    @Fields({
        @Field(store=Store.COMPRESS),
        @Field(name = "sorting_name", analyze = Analyze.NO)
    })
    private String name;

    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "playersClub")
    private Set<Player> players;

}
```

Now when I search into ClubSearchService like this:

```
luceneQuery = queryBuilder
                    ...
                    .onField("name").andField("players.firstName")
                    ...
```

it works fine, but when I want search in other way(PlayerSearchService):

```
               .onField("firstName").andField("lastName").andField("number").andField("country").andField("playersClub.name")
```

there is an error

```
org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to find field playersClub.name in pl.domain.Player
```

Hibernate Search cannot search into ManyToOne item?

Comment: I have set ContainedIn but the OneToMany relation is still not updated. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It was only a tidbit for me, I don't remember exactly what I did. Try to use @IndexedEmbedded as Sanne wrote above.

Comment: This is my Contact
`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contact")
@ContainedIn
@NotAudited
public Set<AttendeeTO> getAttendees() {
 return attendees;
}`

and this is Attendee 
`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ID")
@IndexedEmbedded(depth = 0, includePaths = { "contactId", "merged", "gender", "language", "secondLanguage", "address.country.countryId", "address2.country.countryId" })
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED, withModifiedFlag = false)
public ContactTO getContact() {
 return contact;
}`

Comment: When I update the contact, the index is not updated at attendee leavel. I have to rebuild manually the indexes to have it working.

Comment: parameter depth in IndexEmbedded means what level of the embedded object the main index should consist. Try set depth to 1.

Comment: I was sure I already tried that, but it seems not. It works! Many thanks

Comment: If u think it was helpful for you then give "up" to comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to index `ManyToOne` relations as well.

In most simple cases you have one entity such as `Club` marked as `@Indexed` and then you want to index some of its *fields* and also *embed* via `@IndexedEmbedded` attributes from a related entity `Player`.

So far you got it right, and this is defining essentially the "flattened" schema for your `club` index.

The problem is that when defining the schema for the `player` index you marked `firstname` as an indexed field, but didn't instruct it to embed the relation to `playersClub`. Essentially you're missing the `@IndexedEmbedded` on this property.

To not be confused with the `@ContainedIn` annotation: this is purely to make sure that Hibernate Search will re-index the entities in which it is contained; it is not making both sides embedding each other in a symmetric way.

In more formal terms, the relation established by `@IndexedEmbedded` is a directed graph: if you want it to follow both directions you have to establish them both explicitly.

Comment: hmm. thanks. I thought  that @ContainedIn should to do the trick